# disabling a deactivation guard when routing

Tags: angular

I have a route with the following flow : user navigates from Route A to Route B, these routes are in different modules and each has a activation and a deactivation guard.  The activation guard redirects the user to the last navigated point within the module (it's remembered in ngrx) the deactivation guard checks for any unsaved changes and prompts the user before navigating out.

route A -> Deactivate guard prompts Pending confirm, user clicks Yes, navigation proceeds

route B -> Activation guard kicks in, determines previous point exists, issues a `router.navigateByUrl(previousUrlFromHistory)` and returns false to cancel the current navigation.

The problem here is that in my Activation guard for route B when `navigateByUrl` executes it considers it a brand new navigation cycle FROM route A and this in turn triggers the deactivation guard all over again (cyclical).

So, for this invocation I need to temporarily route without any deactivation guards executing since it's a safe navigation issued by the redirect guard itself.

Is there a way to tell the router itself to navigate without guards?  for example: `router.navigateByUrl(url, { checkDeactivate: false });` or something like that?

I could handle this manually using flags but would rather use a router option if it exists.. I couldn't find anything so far.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here.  I see Angular 7 now has route state that can be passed, so i'm going to pass it as route data and then query the flag in my deactivationGuard which should be simple enough. Thankfully we are transitioning to Angular 7.